# How to make curl connection localhost?

Tags: curl, localhost

i am using curl to get json data from certain api.

But at moment i do it over internet using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

**Is it possible to do it in localhost?**

Idea is to optimise it and save some query time, panel_api.php is in same dir as curl query file.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/panel_api.php?username={$user}&password={$pass}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$source_array = json_decode($html, true);
```

Comment: not possible, unless you've configured your site and apache to treat `localhost` as an official name for the site.and why are you doing a local http request anyways? that's massively inefficient, when you could just call a function in the main code to do whatever this `panel_api.php` is doing.

Comment: So you are hosting the API yourself? Then you could probably(!) just include the API script via the local file system, `include 'path/panel_api.php';`, and set the parameters it expects before via `$_GET['username'] = 'username';` You might need to use output buffering to “catch” the API output; unless you can configure/modify it to return a variable instead of generating output.

Comment: So i could do this ? ---> $username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
ob_start();
include 'panel_api.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
$source_array = json_decode($output, true);